# Rails, Mongoid-Ancestry: Exclude child nodes if parent node is not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ancestry

I have code for displaying main menu:

```
@main_menu = Page.where(active: true).arrange(order: :position)
```

It grabs all nodes with active parameter is set to true. But if the parent node for some children is set to active:false, they connects to grandparent node, and so on. How to avoid this behavior, so if parent node is excluded then all children nodes become excluded too?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is the solution

In ApplicationController:

```
before_filter do
    @main_menu = Page.where(active: true, show_in_main_menu: true).arrange(order: :position)

    def menu_ids(attributes, mids = [])
      attributes.map do |attribute, sub_attributes|
        if sub_attributes.empty?
          mids << attribute.id.to_s
        else
          mids << attribute.id.to_s
          menu_ids(sub_attributes, mids)
        end
      end
      mids
    end
    @menu_ids = menu_ids(@main_menu)
  end
```

In ApplicationHelper:

```
def main_menu(attributes)
    attributes.map do |attribute, sub_attributes|
      if sub_attributes.empty?
        if @menu_ids.include?(attribute.parent_id.to_s)
          content_tag(:li) do
            link_to attribute.name.html_safe, page_path(attribute._id)
          end
        end
      else
        if attribute.parent_id == nil
          content_tag(:li, nil, class: "dropdown") do
            begin
              link_to( attribute.name.html_safe, page_path(attribute._id))+
              (icon('angle-double-right') if !attribute.is_root?)+
              content_tag(:ul, nil) do
                main_menu(sub_attributes)
              end
            end.html_safe
          end
        else
          if @menu_ids.include?(attribute.parent_id.to_s)
            content_tag(:li, nil, class: "dropdown") do
              begin
                link_to( attribute.name.html_safe, page_path(attribute._id))+
                (icon('angle-double-right') if !attribute.is_root?)+
                content_tag(:ul, nil) do
                  main_menu(sub_attributes)
                end
              end.html_safe
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end.join.html_safe
  end
```

And it finally works like I wanted